# Tell Impala to ignore errors and continue

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, impala

I am trying to run a long refresh script using shell nohup,

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
impala-shell -f Refresh.sql -i "landingarea"
```

But every time it hits an error it stops, I have to go into the script fix the error and re run from the beginning, id like it to just run to the end and I can pick up the errors, is this possible?

Shell

```
nohup sh Refresh.sh cat nohup.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use -c **Continues on query failure.**

```
impala-shell -f -c Refresh.sql -i "landingarea"
```

if you donot want to capture the verbose/error message you can problably include --quiet option

```
 impala-shell -f -c -quiet Refresh.sql -i "landingarea"
```

Please go though the documentation link below for more information.

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_shell_options.html

Comment: Excellent answer well explained, thanks for the link and your help :)